# PDO fetchAll on non-object error

Tags: php, pdo

How come when I do this:

```
<?php
$pdo  = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$sql  = $pdo->query("call GetFromCoords($lat, $lng)");

$sql  = $pdo->query("call GetInRadius($zip, $dist)");
$rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /home/ryannaddyps/weblyize.com/Party/nearby.php on line 28

But if I run the second query on a new connection, it works fine?

Comment: has $pdo been initialized?

Comment: Yes, it has the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [nextRowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php)():

```
$pdo  = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
$sql  = $pdo->query("call GetFromCoords($lat, $lng)");

$sql->nextRowset(); // This

$sql  = $pdo->query("call GetInRadius($zip, $dist)");
$rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your SQL query triggers an error? According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php), `PDO::query` returns `FALSE` (i.e. a non-object) when the query fails.

Enable `error_reporting` and `display_errors` or alternatively initialize the connection with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.